# More than one ActiveRecord query at once?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

Here's an action in my controller. What it currently does is display all Guides that have a least any spelling of the word 'abyss' in it. What I'd like to do is display all guides that have either any spelling of 'abyss' or any spelling of 'cat' in it as well.

I've tried all sorts of `'%cat%'` combinations, but can't find the right place to put it.

How do I make this work?

```
 def abyss
    t = Guide.arel_table
    @guides = Guide.where(t[:title].matches('%abyss%'))
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try with `or` as follows:

```
def abyss
  t = Guide.arel_table
  @guides = Guide.where(t[:title].matches('%abyss%').or(t[:title].matches('%cat%')))
end
```

Comment: undefined method `or' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation []>

Comment: @DylanRichards, I had a missing closing parenthesis in my answer, which I've updated.  Testing this query shows correct `or` in `where` clause.  Can you give this a try again and if you encounter an error, post that error with stack trace in your question.

Comment: Your correction worked. Thank you very much. You've been very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

You can use find_by_sql to simplify such queries:

```
def abyss
  @guides = Guide.find_by_sql(["select * from guides where title LIKE ? OR title LIKE ?", '%abyss%', '%cat%'])
end
```